# Which of these expressions is correct? "Debe ser" vs "Debe de ser"

Tags: verbos, preposiciones

I have always had this doubt.

Which of these expressions is properly used and when to use each of them?

> Debe haber sido un accidente
>
> Debe **de** haber sido un accidente (is this a mistake?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example both forms are correct.

According to the RAE about [the uses of `deber`](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=deber):

- Deber + infinitive denotes an obligation

> Debo cumplir con mi misión  <sub>I must accomplish my mission</sub> .

In this case (denoting an obligation) is an error to introduce the preposition *"de"*.

> Debo **de** cumplir con mi misión (WRONG!!)

- Deber **de** + infinitive is used to express a supposition, guess or probability

> No hay luz en su casa. Deben de haber salido  <sub>There is no light at their place. They must have gone out</sub>
>
> Debe de haber sido un accidente.

When expressing a supposition, you can use both "deber de + infinitive" or just "deber + infinitive".

> Marianita, su hija, debe tener unos veinte años  <sub>Marianita, their daughter, must be twenty years old</sub>  (expresses a guess, not an obligation)

Since you example denotes a supposition, both forms provided are OK.

Comment: The answer is correct, but "debe + de" would be the construction of choice in this case. Originally, both constructions had different meanings, as Diego explains; but, through time, the use of *deber*, without preposition, was extended to also cover the meaning of *deber de*, so the RAE accepted it a few years ago. But using *deber + de* removes the ambiguity from the sentence. *Debe haber sido un accidente* might also mean that, once the evidence has been analysed, the only logical conclusion is that this was an accident.